why languages need an import/include/using etc to refer to other code in other files?
In various languages I came across during my career require some import/using/include etc. to refer to the code in other file.
while the same languages also require a package manager or a list of files to be provided. for instance

in C++ all CPP files need to be provided to the compiler
in PHP there is a autoload.php that refers to all the files, and autoload is then included from thereon
in typescript import is used but the files are specified the tsconfig file.

so if all compilers need a list of files, when it comes to single file compilation, are the missing symbols can be marked and compilation of each file would result in some symbols to be resolved. Most probably a multipass compiler would be more suitable here.
so why haven't we seen any compiler even in 2024 that does it and not require us to provide the import/include etc in the files.

In C# you don't need to import other files to access the code. The `using´ statement is used to open namespaces, but is independent of files.

... what JacquesB wrote about C# is AFAIK true for Java as well. So you may ask why in the three languages you mentioned imports or includes are required, but in general your question is based on a wrong premise.

itas not, even in java n c#, you need to include, import or using. my question is why compiler can figure that out? maybe they are old languages but even in new languages, i do not see any language has an alternative strategy

"so why haven't we seen any compiler even in 2024" – What do you mean "we"? I am sure plenty of people have seen such a compiler. Most Smalltalks work this way, Self works this way, Newspeak works this way. Go arguably works this way.

"even in java n c#, you need to include, import or using.". Nonsense. just write System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");, or System.out.println("Hello, World!"); - no using required.

You've got to provide it eventually somehow. What happens when you need to call the function?

you have AI available, the compiler can track and identify the pattern and use right package

@SimpleFellow oh god, that's the worst possible answer for package management

There are many times my IDE has automatically figured out what import my code needs and autogenerated it for me. It’s tempting to think the compiler could also do it. And it could.
But now to understand what code was compiled and ran we have to look up a bunch of compiler rules and  figure out how they would have been applied to whatever state the code library was in when compiled. Yuck.
Sorry but debugging is hard enough. Give me something explicit.

Also, my IDE gets it often enough wrong. Which would mean more bugs. Sometimes very subtle ones cause you might have the same class but different versions available and picking the wrong one might just so ever slightly change its behaviour...

compiler can keep track of changes and updates its db of symbols.

@SimpleFellow yes. It can also encode it in the blockchain. But could I please have it somewhere easy to find?

nice, now consider the scenario where you have a need of an import but the class (for example) in question exists (by name) in a dozen different possible imports you have linked to your project directly or indirectly. Your auto-import system is almost certain to choose the wrong one, leading to problems either at compile time or worse, runtime.

There's a difference between what you could do, and what you want to do.
Let's say my program uses three files, X, A and B. X uses a function made available in A, but spells it wrong and by coincidence it matches a function made available in B. Since B is not included, the compiler cannot tell me that I made some mistake. If neither A nor B need to be included, it is impossible for the compiler to know that I made a mistake, and at runtime my code in X will just call the wrong function.
I love redundancy.
And there is always the question: Which other files do I have to look at to understand the code in X? Answer: Look for the include statements, and that's what you need to know. If it's not included (directly or indirectly) then you don't need to understand it to understand X. Worst case, you have to go through all the files to find which ones are relevant to some particular code.

Even without misspellings in the mix, many, many libraries export symbols with the same names. Without explicit imports, every library in the world would tread on every other library's toes.

Similarly, if you have a library that adapts a bunch of platform's specific things into a unified interface, you'll have intentional name duplication within that library.

fully qualified names in Java and C# work without "using", which invalidates last paragraph (and is very annoying).

I love redundancy. -- Me too! That is why I define the same function multiple times with several common misspelt names.

my idea is that the imported libraries are mentioned. compiler should skim thru them to create a tiny db of its own and during compilation should check if the symbol is present I in its own db. that db is updated only when you change the imported packages..do it's not really about any library and any package but only the ones that are part of the program

@SimpleFellow Nobody says it cannot be done. I say it is not what you want.

Some languages like Java and C# work as you describe. In C# you can use code from other files in the same project without importing anything explicitly. Namespaces are optional and if you don't use different namespaces in your project, you don't need using. (Even if you do use namespaces, you can always use fully qualified names instead of using statements).
So your next question is then probably: Why doesn't all languages work like this, since it seems simpler not having to import any files?
There are a bunch of trade-offs involved.
Size of compilation unit
The C# compiler have to parse and compile all files in the project in order to compile a single file. This is not a problem with small projects, but with larger projects it becomes a performance issue. The solution is to split the code into multiple projects which are compiled separately. But then you are back to square one because projects need to explicitly import other projects and you have to be careful to avoid circular references between projects.
Deterministic import order
In dynamic languages, loading a file means executing the definitions in the file. Files have to be loaded in a specific order when definitions depend on other definitions. Import statement is a simple way for a file to declare which dependencies it depends on.
Some statically typed languages like F# also require deterministic import order since you can only refer to previously defined code. This prevents circular definitions.
C# on the other hand allows circular dependencies between classes which may be convenient but may also lead to sloppy architecture.
Namespaces
For any project above a certain size you need some namespacing mechanism to avoid name collisions. Even if you are careful to not reuse names in your own code, you will have collision across third-party packages. Importing files is just a straightforward way to manage what names are in scope. C#'s namespacing system is independent of files, but it turns out people usually let namespaces follow the folder structure of the project, which means in the end using's in practice work like imports.
This is only scratching the surface of the different considerations and trade-offs which go into the design of module and import systems.

In older C# versions you'd also need to have which files you used specified in your csproj. Visual Studio would handle it automatically (and cause too many merge errors) but they would be like <Compile Include="Authentication\Manager.cs" /> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-items?view=vs-2022#create-items-in-a-project-file

In the case of C++, it's because they are following the compilation model of C, for backwards compatibility.
When C was developed, computers didn't gave gigabytes of RAM.  It was measured in kilobytes (or kilowords - they weren't always multiples of 8 bits then). This means that it wasn't possible to load the whole source code of an application into RAM at one time, and still have enough memory left for the compiler itself.
So C was designed so that each source file could be compiled independently of the others.  Header files were used to tell the compiler about things that were in other source files, but the compiler couldn't see them.  Without the header files, the compiler wouldn't know what external variables or functions there were, and so couldn't compile the right code to access them.
Once all the C files have been compiled, a linker will run to merge all the individual object files together, and insert the correct addresses for everything.
Even now, C++ compilers still use that same model.

It is not a problem of memory. Compiler does not need to keep the whole compilation unit in memory. It is a problem of speed - header is quicker to read and compile than a whole unit.

Your main argument is that having a crucial project configuration, imports are redundant.
However import statements also indicate the exact path, as names can be ambiguous. One can easily import the wrong class. Also if one needs a new library class, an IDE may help finding the class, even when not in the project's configuration.
Imports give us a higher language than package lists. They can be checked at a source ("unneeded import") and take for instance Modula-2. There a definition module is like a C header, but compiled. The implementation  module again, can use internal libraries. This allows less compilation and linkage and better software development (version steps). Modula-2's module system is the package manager.
As you say, nowadays recompiling everything is more feasible, but isolation of module usage is important with growing complexity.

interesting, what I'm thinking is that in case of a program when there are no conflicting namespaces, the imports are defined in configuration. the compiler can create a hash list of functions of each module. in case of conflict it would ask for the collision resolution. then once the compiler has the say "a databse of all exports of all functions of the imported modules". it can work on the source code without needing those import statements at the top of every file because whenever it encounters an unknown function it can refer to its db. and every file that it compiled it adds to that db
